# Convert i32 into f32

Tags: type-conversion, zig

How can I convert a i32 into a f32 in Zig Language?

I want to count appearances of values in a for loop and afterwards get the percentages in a smooth floating number.

```
var partial : i32 = 0;
var total : i32 = 2000;
  

for (arr[0..total]) |value| {
    if(value < 200) inCircle = inCircle +  1;
}

const result = partial / total;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Zig 0.11+

Use [`@floatFromInt`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#floatFromInt):

```
const result = @as(f32, @floatFromInt(partial)) / @as(f32, @floatFromInt(total));
```

If you're confused about the need to use [`@as`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#as): see [Result Location Semantics](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Result-Location-Semantics) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856333/944911).

#### Zig 0.10

You need to use [`@intToFloat`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#intToFloat) function. Like this:

```
const result = @intToFloat(f32, partial) / @intToFloat(f32, total);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was to conversion method I've looked for. Can you provide a documentation link as well?

Comment: @CitrusPunk It's in the answer: https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#intToFloat

Comment: I do get it's important to be explicit, but the 0.10 => 0.11 change feels ... verbose. Is there a design rationale for this?

Comment: @sigint The 0.11 changes make the code more streamlined, but as a side effect the code becomes more verbose in some situations. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856333/944911) answer and [this](https://ziglang.org/download/0.11.0/release-notes.html#Cast-Inference) section of the 0.11 changelog.