# How do I (unsafely) cast from `u64` to `i64` in Zig?

Tags: zig

I have a `u64` value that I need to cast to `i64`. `@as`, `@intCast`, and `@truncate` all give compiler errors because not all `u64` values fit into `i64`. That's fair enough but in this case I need an `i64` and I'm willing to accept an error/crash in the unlikely event that the value doesn't fit. Does Zig have a function or operator to do this?

Comment: `@as(i64, @intCast(value))` should just work.

Comment: Why does that work but not `@intCast(i64, value)`?

Comment: https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#intCast because the u64 might have a value that is outside of the range of an i64 so there is no guarantee of getting the same numerical value

Comment: `@intCast(i64, value)` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

In 0.11, the syntax of [`@intCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/#intCast) (and some others) has [changed](https://ziglang.org/download/0.11.0/release-notes.html#Cast-Inference) slightly.

`@intCast` no longer takes a type argument. Instead, you must rely on [Result Location Semantics](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/#Result-Location-Semantics):

- `const x: T = e` gives `e` a result type of `T`
- `@as(T, e)` gives `e` a result type of `T`
- `return e` gives `e` a result type of the function's return type
- `S{ .f = e }` gives `e` a result type of the type of the field `S.f`
- `f(e)` gives `e` a result type of the first parameter type of `f`

For example:

```
const result: i64 = @intCast(value);
```

or

```
const result = @as(i64, @intCast(value));
```